# SqlBulkCopy failed in SQLServer 2012

Tags: c#, sql-server-2012, sqlbulkcopy

My below code is working on my SQL Server 2008 but the same is failing in SQL Server 2012. Getting no exception or error, data is not inserting into table.

```
using(var bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(objsqlConnection.ConnectionString, SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepNulls & SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepIdentity)) {
    bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Clear();
    bulkCopy.BatchSize = Dttable.Rows.Count;

    foreach(DataColumn col in Dttable.Columns) {
        bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(col.ColumnName, col.ColumnName);
    }

    bulkCopy.BulkCopyTimeout = 600;
    bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = Servertable;
    destinationTbName = Servertable;

    bulkCopy.SqlRowsCopied += new SqlRowsCopiedEventHandler(OnSqlRowsTransfer);
    bulkCopy.NotifyAfter = Dttable.Rows.Count;

    bulkCopy.WriteToServer(Dttable);

    return true;
}
```

Is this any permission related issue? How can I solve it? Please help

Comment: Look in the server management logs for errors

Comment: log is... Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 8.
Login failed for user 'nayasa'. Reason: Password did not match that for the login provided. [CLIENT: <local machine>]

Comment: So you're using the wrong password..

Comment: no.. I can login into management studio using the same password

Comment: Check your connection string. Are you talking to the correct db? If you have something in the string that mentions "Attach" and your program does not run inside a Asp.net page you are likey writing to the wrong db

Comment: I double checked and single insertion is done without any problem.

Comment: So you created and executed a new single insertion method using the same objsqlConnection.ConnectionString?

Comment: Soooo... What was the fix?